# Which of the following is/are not used as a reason for justifying the following steps in solving this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a friendly disagreement with my daughter's teacher regarding the problem below and would like your input. Thank you.

Question: Which of the following is/are not used as a reason for justifying the following steps in solving this equation? 
$\frac{7}{2}n=3n+4$ 
$2(\frac{7}{2}n)=2(3n+4)$ 
$7n=6n+8$ 
$7n-6n=6n-6n+8$ 
$n=8$

Choices: 
Multiplication Property 
Distributive Property 
Subtraction Property 
Combining like terms

Edit: More context. This is 7th grade math and is originally a multiple choice question. The "correct" answer according to the teacher's answer key is "Combining like terms," but I believe each reason is used. I provide my answer.

Comment: Well, what is your view?  I don't think that terms like "Multiplication Property" or "Subtraction Property" are universal, so perhaps you might indicate what you believe they mean in this context.

Comment: This is 7th grade context so consider definitions in that setting. That is, multiplication property means if $a=b$ then $ca=cb$ and subtraction property means if $a=b$ then $a-c=b-c$ where all are reals.

Comment: Strange questions, since all properties are obviously used.

Comment: @Peter this was also my answer and the source of disagreement. The teacher said that the last item, $n=8$, is just "the process" of subtraction property and does not use "combining like terms." I was trying to point out that each line must have a reason and subtraction property cannot be used twice in different contexts but the teacher insists otherwise. I wanted to clarify this in case my daughter encounters a similar problem.

Comment: Why couldn't a property be used twice?  Or half a dozen times?  More broadly, this is all very vague.  one could argue that $7n-6n=(7-6)\times n=n$ is an application of the Distributive Law, for instance.  I mean, that's what it is.

Comment: What's the definition of "combining like terms"? Isn't addition/ subtraction just an example of that?

Comment: The point being that these questions do not have unique, well-posed answers.  One could defend multiple answers with ease.

Comment: @Andrei, exactly, and here the subtraction property is used to gather like terms.

Comment: Indeed, and the subtraction property is a form of the addition property: the adding of a negative quantity to each side of an equation.

Comment: @lulu I meant that you can't have two distinct definitions for the same property. If subtraction property means if $a=b$ then $a-c=b-c$, then it doesn't fit to use that as the reasoning for $7n-6n=n$. Of course you can use the same property more than once, but you cannot define it differently each time you use it.

Comment: Apparently, they do the combination during the subtraction.  To be consistent, they should also have done distribution at the same time as multiplication. $\quad$

Comment: That's what I was also thinking. I thought maybe it's a trick question and there isn't a "combining like terms property." However, the teacher also had a different example where the reason for a step is "combining like terms," essentially the same as this except it does not start with subtraction property prior. That is, the given is say $2n+n=5$ and to get to $3n=5$, she cites "combining like terms."

Comment: Of course the two last steps could have been emerged , but this was not done. From $7n-6n$ to $n$ and on the right side as well, "combining like terms" is definitely used , there is not the slightest room for a discussion. So, the teacher is wrong, and the answer must be "none of them".

Comment: This is anyway a terrible exercise. Usually , mathematical results cannot be discussed , there is only one correct solution , this exercise apparently tried to work around this principle.

Comment: @amWhy The "subtraction property" only states that you can subtract something from both sides of the equation and maintain equality. Actually doing the subtraction is not subtraction property, just subtraction, right? But in this case, the subtraction deals with algebraic terms for which basic subtraction does not formally work. We need to deal with the "n"'s and the way this is done is using combining like terms. At least that's how I understand it. Of course, in practice, this is all done shorthand, but I think it's important to do it right and to the t for 7th graders to understand.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{7}{2}n=3n+4$; Given 
$2(\frac{7}{2}n)=2(3n+4)$; Multiplication Property  
$7n=6n+8$; Distributive Property 
$7n-6n=6n-6n+8$; Subtraction Property 
$n=8$; Combining like terms 
Therefore, each of the choices are used and there is no correct answer.

Comment: The correct answer is "none of them" , since all properties are used.

Comment: Agreed, but like I said, this was originally a multiple choice question, and "none of them" was not an option.